# sorting large text data

Tags: python, sorting, bigdata

I have a large file (100 million lines of tab separated values - about 1.5GB in size). What is the fastest known way to sort this based on one of the fields?

I have tried hive. I would like to see if this can be done faster using python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you considered using the *nix [`sort`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sort%201) program? in raw terms, it'll probably be faster than most Python scripts.

Use `-t $'\t'` to specify that it's tab-separated, `-k n` to specify the field, where `n` is the field number, and `-o outputfile` if you want to output the result to a new file.
Example:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 4 -o sorted.txt input.txt
```

Will sort `input.txt` on its 4th field, and output the result to `sorted.txt`

Comment: the unix sort command is a very powerful tool indeed. You can control the format of the field to sort on (numeric, date, etc.) and the amount of memory which the program can allocate, performing a split + merge sort if necessary.

Comment: alex can you give an example? The sort program on its own is taking quite a long time ... of the order of 40 mins. This may have something to do with memory allocation or disk IO. I'm not sure how to figure out what the bottleneck is, but I'm guessing that your suggestion may be useful.

Comment: one error in the solution above: to use only the 2nd field, one needs -k 2,2 ... so it is not zero indexed (at least not on Kubuntu 11.04's version of sort).

Answer (score 6):

you want to build an in-memory index for the file:

1. create an empty list
2. `open` the file
3. read it line by line (using `f.readline()`, and store in the list a tuple consisting of the value on which you want to sort (extracted with `line.split('\t').strip()`) and the offset of the line in the file (which you can get by calling `f.tell()` before calling `f.readline()`)
4. `close` the file
5. `sort` the list

Then to print the sorted file, reopen the file and for each element of your list, use `f.seek(offset)` to move the file pointer to the beginning of the line, `f.readline()` to read the line and `print` the line.

Optimization: you may want to store the length of the line in the list, so that you can use `f.read(length)` in the printing phase.

Sample code (optimized for readability, not speed):

```
def build_index(filename, sort_col):
    index = []
    f = open(filename)
    while True:
        offset = f.tell()
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        length = len(line)
        col = line.split('\t')[sort_col].strip()
        index.append((col, offset, length))
    f.close()
    index.sort()
    return index

def print_sorted(filename, col_sort):
    index = build_index(filename, col_sort)
    f = open(filename)
    for col, offset, length in index:
        f.seek(offset)
        print f.read(length).rstrip('\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'somefile.txt'
    sort_col = 2
    print_sorted(filename, sort_col)
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea IMO. This way you are to make a list which can eat even 8GB of RAM or more. (a python empty string is 40bytes, multiply it by 2 as you want to store 2 values in this tuple and by 100 milions - number of lines the author specified in the problem). It was the very point of the question that the data is large...

Answer (score 4):

Split up into files that can be sorted in memory. Sort each file in memory. Then merge the resulting files.

Merge by reading a portion of each of the files to be merged. The same amount from each file leaving enough space in memory for the merged result. Once merged saving this. Repeating adding blocks of merged data onto the file.

This minimises the file i/o and moving around the file on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the file in a good relational database, index it on the field your are interested in and then read the ordered items.

Comment: i.e. even sqlite would work