# Sorting csv by number of columns in each row

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a large (2.2GB) text delimited file that holds chemical paths that I search when I want to go from chemical A to chemical B. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way (preferably in python) that I could sort the file by number of columns in a row?

Example:

CSV:

```
A B C D
E F G
H I
J K L M N
```

Should sort to:

```
H I
E F G
A B C D
J K L M N
```

I've been thinking of making a hashtable of row lengths and rows, but as the csv files get larger: (we're running longest path on a chemical network and the 2.2gb (30mil paths) is only length <= 10), I anticipate this approach may not be the fastest.

Comment: I would build an index and sort that. For example, for each line in your chemical paths file, create a tuple in the index of `(length, pointer_to_line)`.  The length is easy, because you could just do `len(row.split())`. The pointer to the line could be done through `f.tell()` or something similar. Sort the index. Once sorted, use it to grab lines out of your chemical paths file in order, which you can write to a new file. Edit: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079473/sorting-large-text-data) might be helpful.

Comment: My first reaction is to put this data in a database rather than trying to forcibly work with a CSV (although perhaps you've already read the data from a database!). You'd have the benefits of a database and be able to use Python + SQL to do more types of data analysis in the future if the need arises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for splitting them into separate files based on the length, then joining them back together afterwards - something like:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from itertools import chain
```

Keep a reference dict of file length->output file. Where a file is already opened, then write to it, or create a new temporary file.

```
output = {}
with open('input') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        length = len(line.split())
        output.setdefault(length, TemporaryFile()).write(line)
```

As Steven Rumbalski has pointed out, this can be also done with a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(TemporaryFile)
...
output[length].write(line)
```

The temporary files will all be pointing to the end of the file. Reset them to the beginning so that when reading through them we get the data again...

```
for fh in output.values():
    fh.seek(0)
```

Take the rows from each file in increasing order of length... and write them all to the final output file.

```
with open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(chain.from_iterable(v for k,v in sorted(output.iteritems())))
```

Python should then clean up the temporary files upon program exit...

Comment: Very pythonic, not really readable for the new comer. Should be commented in my opinion.

Comment: @btoueg annotated it slightly - let me know if you think it needs anything further

Comment: +1.  I would have preferred `output = defaultdict(TemporaryFile)`, but that's just a matter of taste.  The word "should" in your final sentence reads like you are exhorting the OP to clean up the files.  Better would be "Python should (will?) clean up the temporary files upon program exit."  Also, the last word is misspelled.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Good point about `defaultdict` - I didn't use that previously as I was originally manually opening files so wasn't quite so convenient to use that as a factory. As for the rest, I'll make edits now

Comment: @JonClements incase you're wondering how well your algorithm did, it took 2 hours and 36 minutes to sort 30,000,000 rows!

Comment: @Darkstarone that seems pitiful - Maybe a good 5 - 10 minutes on a slow disk, but 2 and a half hours? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: I agree, it seems strange, I'm chucking on an SSD on Monday to see if I can increase the speed!