# Python - Grouping (or looping) based on column value (or subsetting)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataset that has 3 million rows and 1,200 "groups" - let's call them Last Names.

Here's what the data set looks like:

```
LastName    FirstName

Smith       Rachael
Smith       John
Smith       Rachael
Johnson     Bob
Johnson     Laura
Johnson     Laura
```

I want to look at each last name separately, and do something to the first names within each last name. For instance, I might want to find out which first name is the most prevalent within the last name of Smith, then add that as its own column (but in reality it's much more complicated than that). I need to keep all of the rows intact (in other words I need to keep every Smith and every Johnson).

```
LastName    FirstName   HighestFreq

Smith       Rachael     Rachael
Smith       John        Rachael
Smith       Rachael     Rachael
Johnson     Bob         Laura
Johnson     Laura       Laura
Johnson     Laura       Laura
```

I don't know if the best way is to split up the data set into 1,200 data sets and then merge back together at the end or do some kind of loop. I'm very new to Python and haven't been able to figure out how to do it correctly. I've figured out the code I need to look at the individual rows, just now how to look only at one last name at a time.

Also, if subsetting is the best way, I'd need to name the sets in a loop, since I'm obviously not going to name 1,200 data sets manually.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think you need to create 1,200 data sets but why not. Sorting your original data set by the category of interest is always a good start (which might not be trivial if your data set is to big to hold in memory). After sorting you can most likely hold all your counts for one category in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the length of returned result, you can use `transform` after `groupby`, and then use `value_counts()` function with `index` to get the most frequent item in each group:

```
df['HighestFreq'] = (df.groupby('LastName')['FirstName']
                       .transform(lambda g: g.value_counts().index[0]))
df
```

[image]

Comment: You should mention that this solution is based on NumPy and NumPy might not be available since it requires some system dependencies. However, it seem to be a good idea to use something that solves the underlying memory management problems for you. I was thinking of sqlite but kept thinking what the best solution in "pure" Python would be.

Comment: I don't know much about the under hood of Pandas library, this solution uses pandas. I believe if pandas depends on Numpy, you should get it installed along the way when you install pandas?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the Pandas tag on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help all

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this. Does anyone know what happens if there is a tie? Let's say Rachael is the first name 3 times and Linda is the first name 3 times. What happens? Can I tell it which one to pick as the "most frequent"?

Answer (score 0):

Here just in case without Pandas (see below with Pandas):

Sort the file by category you want to group on, either with Unix command or a Python script, see here [sorting large text data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079473/sorting-large-text-data).

Than iterate over the sorted file and get the metrics you want for each category. Since all instances of a category are now next to each other you only need to hold the result in memory.

If you want to skip the sorting you could also iterate over the file several times (but that might be slow). Your idea of saving intermediate results to disk would work of course.

Advanced reading: This is basically a map-reduce-operation: Create subgroups process them separately and then consolidate the results.